# How do I attach UI data to logic data?

Tags: gui, inventory

I'm attempting to write an inventory system(C++, doesn't need to be huge), that later on should be able to be drawn in a GUI.

In the file structure, I think it would be best to put both information about the item itself and references to graphics, etc. in one file.

But how does that translate into code? How should I tell the renderer, for example which sprite to draw for which item and where to do that. Should I only have the CInventory and the CItem class, containing both logic and sprite information, or should I create separate logic and GUI inventory(in this case meaning both CInventory and CItem) classes which are then linked by a common item-id for example?

Answers are always appreciated :)

Comment: Are you asking if you should put all of the item logic in the inventory class?

Comment: No what I meant was that I would have an inventory and an item class, both separate from each other, and put both the logic code and GUI information inside these classes. So that the item for example contains data like the value or the strength of a weapon but also references to necessary icons and such.

Comment: I've posted an answer that can hopefully aid you.  I am not 100% on your question, but the code I have posted takes care of how to draw Items in different states.  Hopefully this can give you an idea of how to handle different classes as they are moved throughout a typical game.  It is c# code, but I trust you can decipher what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the base of your question lies inventory management.  In this case, inventory is simply a container of inventory items, where inventory items can be a plethora of game objects.  These game objects could be consumables, armor, quest items, or any other game specific concept.  This container includes a way to add a game object to its internal list or remove it; very generic.

You also need a system to render your inventory UI.  This system knows how to obtain the player inventory, iterate it and find out what game objects exist in the inventory.  This system is what is responsible for taking UI events and delegating those into actions against specific game objects.

When you open your inventory, the inventory UI system iterates the game objects in the inventory, queries each object for a specific component or attribute that identifies what sprite to render and creates the appropriate UI objects so that specific gets rendered in the right UI slot.  It is possible that multiple game objects in your inventory represent the same sprite perhaps.

The beauty of the above is that in a client/server situation, the inventory management system would be managed by the server while the inventory ui system is managed by the client.  While both can coexist in a non-client/server game, the separation is still useful for decoupling UI from logic.

Comment: This `Pickable` component, is it a pointer that gets added to the inventory? And when you say the inventory module looks at the item to determine the sprite, does that mean that the inventory class handles both the management of the inventory and the rendering? Because I was having problems with this kind of close coupling before which is the reason why I asked this question in the first place..

Comment: @therufuser I edited by answer and hopefully it's clearer what I was trying to convey.

Answer (score 0):

The Inventory should be a list of Items.  When the user picks up the Item from the ground, it is moved into the list, and removed from a list of Dropped Items in the game.  When the user moves the item to his equipment, the item is removed from the inventory and moved into a slot in the equipment class.

An Item should only exist in one context.

The Item class should have a draw method that will take care of it being drawn if it is dropped on the ground.

The Inventory class should handle the drawing of its items for each inventory slot you provide.

The draw method of the Item class is no longer called once it has become a child of the Inventory.

If you would like a clear example of this, one can be found on my GitHub : https://github.com/shroeder/GameRPG/tree/LukesBranch/Game/Game.  Feel free to reference this code, I think it is tailored to your question.

Comment: A look at your code kind of answered my question. If I understand correctly you have an item class, which holds texture and position information. Then in your global Draw method the Item class basically draws itself through a call to the Draw() member. One question I have though is: do these Items provide any effects? That is something I couldn't quite understand from your code. But I think they don't which would mean they are purely GUI-elements, right?